# How to control when to plot a seaborn chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code in which I create a distribution chart of data, get the data of the curve plotted, and calculate the area above with an integral. But I want to decide if the charts have to be plotted graphically or not. Because sometimes I want to plot to see the distributions graphically, but other times I only want to see the numeric results of the areas calculated.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(marcos), ncols=1, figsize=(5, 2.5*len(marcos)))

for i, m in enumerate(marcos):
    axs[i].set(ylabel=m)
    axs[i].set_xlim(-marcos_x_lim[i],marcos_x_lim[i])
    sns.distplot(data[data['color']=='verde'][m], hist=False, color="g", kde_kws={"shade": True}, ax=axs[i])

    meanG = data[data['color']=='verde'][m].mean()
    medianG = data[data['color']=='verde'][m].median()
    axs[i].axvline(meanG, color='g', linestyle='-')
    axs[i].axvline(medianG, color='g', linestyle='--')

    #Get the data from the KDE line
    xdata_v, ydata_v = axs[i].get_lines()[0].get_data()

    area_v_pos = scipy.integrate.trapz(...)
```

I have tried with `plt.ioff()`, but it's not working, the charts are always displayed in the console. I'm using Spyder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.close` and `plt.show()` -- e.g.,

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/mtcars.csv').rename({'Unnamed: 0':'car'}, axis=1)

for col in ['hp', 'disp', 'cyl', 'gear']:
    plt.scatter(df[col], df['mpg'])
    plt.title(col)
    # plt.savefig() 
    # etc.
    if col in ['hp', 'disp']:
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.close()
```